# Mail digest with Office365 Group or Distribution list

Tags: microsoft-office-365, office365

Are there any options either in an Office365 Group or Distribution list that allows the messages to be sent in a digest form similar to how Mailman works? I have searched but I cannot seem to find this information.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, Office365 has only the option to automatically send mail summary information each week, we don't have the option to send message in a digest form.

For more information you can refer to the following article:

[Message center in Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/message-center?view=o365-worldwide)